# Scroll by a variable double or float in Selenium (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, scroll

I'm new to Selenium and revisiting programming in general after a long hiatus, so apologies if this isn't a good question. I have a webpage with a bunch of tiles (typically 4 per row, a whole bunch of rows) whose height and width vary based on the size of the window. After every row I want to scroll **up** by the height of one tile. Here's what I have (where eachtile is a list containing all the tiles):

```
double ImageHeight = eachtile.getSize().getHeight();
double f = 1.04*ImageHeight;
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-f);");
```

I've tried all variations of quotes and minus signs in the (0,-f) expression and no matter what I get an error saying that f is undefined. Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,arguments[0]);",-f);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Or try another way, scroll to the next item in the list each time:

```
for (WebElement tile : tileList) {
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", tile);
}
```